# QT,C++: Disable file renaming/moving/delete

Tags: c++, qt, file, permissions

Normal file permissions that we have are READ & WRITE. Setting READ permission on a file just blocks writing. But the file can be renamed, moved, deleted,etc.
Is there any QT,c++ api like windows security tab seen in file properties where there are more permissions like "Full Control, Modify,etc" which when set doesn't allow user to delete, move,rename the files.

[image: Security Permissions]

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer, buddy. This function sets permissions for a file (From 
Qt Documentation) : 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#setPermissions

And Here is all the kinds of permissions you can set on your file : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#Permission-enum